# Visual Studio 2010 compile error with std::string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, stdstring

So this is possibly the strangest thing I've seen recently and was curious how this could happen.  The compiler gave me an error saying that std::string is undefined when used as a return type but not when used as a parameter in methods of a class!

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// forward declarations
class CLocalReference;
class CResultSetHandle;

class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass() {}
~MyClass {}

void Retrieve(const CLocalReference& id, CResultSetHandle& rsh, std::string& item); // this is fine
const std::string Retrieve(const CLocalReference& id, CResultSetHandle& rsh); // this fails with std::string is undefined?!?!
};
```

Doing a Rebuild All it still happened I had to choose clean solution and then Rebuild All again after for the universe to realign.  While it's resolved for the moment I'd still like to know what could have caused this because I'm at a loss as to why when there should be no conflicts especially when I always use fully qualified names for STL.

Comment: could you please paste the original error?

Comment: The destructor should be

`~MyClass() {}`

Except from that, it compiles fine for me. I would guess it's a VS2010 bug, or the error is somewhere else in your code. (You know, *even Microsoft* makes bugs!!)

Comment: What error does the compiler report?  Can you reproduce the problem?  If it's not reproducible, any number of things could have happened, and it may very well not have been the fault of the compiler.

Comment: This isn't your original code, you wouldn't have (didn't mention) other errors.

Comment: It compiles fine on VS2010 for me. (after fixing the destructor typo and adding empty bodies for the other two classes.)

Comment: @PigBen: Seems like he means that Intellisense is giving him an error and not the compiler.

Comment: My best guess is that it was related to some object files that were created with a debug build that did not get cleaned by doing Rebuild All in release ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a compiler bug. I have seen several others in VS2010.

Comment: In particular, the dependency checker probably gets confused when you change certain header files and not others.